# Concrete non trivial computation of Morse homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, morse-theory

I am studying Morse homology and have found only examples on spheres and tori so far. Of course the homology of these manifolds is better understood by other more standard methods, so I am having difficulties understanding what is the gain of this homology theory. I know there is some kind of "conceptual" gain in this approach to homology, since it leads to some useful generalization to the infinite-dimensional case. Anyway, I would like to see some finite dimensional example in which the construction of the Morse-Smale-Witten complex is actually easier (or more natural, in any sense) then "classical algebraic-topological methods".

Comment: [Let's wait for answers but] I've always thought it's mainly useful for (co)homology of loop space and such [and not in finite-dimensional situation]...

Answer (score 1):

I like the functions of Bott on the projective spaces $\mathbb{C}P^n$. These are the following functions:

$$
f_n([z_0,\ldots,z_n])=\frac{\sum_i i|z_i|^2}{\sum_i |z_i|^2}.
$$

These are Morse. It is a good exercise to compute the critical points and indices. Then you will see that you don't need to worry about the differential! There are similar examples on other Grasmannians, Flag varieties etc..

Of course Loop spaces are also good examples, albeit not finite dimensional.